# DNS & Namesevers working for one domain but not the other. Same settings

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, nameserver

So here is my current set up:
ns1.hutber & ns2.hutber.com are pointing to hutber.com via c1domains.com
ns1.hutber & ns2.hutber.com are pointing to wingspartytime.com via 123-reg

hutber.com is working perfectly
[image]

wingspartytime.com as far as plesk is concerned i believe it is set up in much the same way, 123-reg's name servers are set to the same, ns1, ns1.hutber.com. The only difference i can see is that in the hutber.com it has ns1.hutber.com A 77.68.108.121 in the DNS settings in plesk. 
[image]

When doing a DNS lookup on both domains i get the following:

hutber.com

> A record found: 77.68.108.120

wingspartytime.com

> None of the nameservers responded correctly.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like ns1.hutber.com has a zone configured for wingspartytime.com.

The following does get you to ns1.hutber.com.  I think this is due to who your domain's delegated nameservers are set to at the registrar (123reg) rather than these ns records based on the dig +trace output.  I'm not sure what those other records there are doing here as these would need to be on ns1.hutber.com and ns2.hutber.com and not on your plesk server.  Unless these are one in the same which isn't clear.

```
dig wingspartytime.com +trace
```

Once the query gets to ns1.hutber.com it appears as though those name servers don't know how to answer to the query.  So it's returning SERVFAIL.

```
dig wingspartytime.com @ns1.hutber.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 43349
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wingspartytime.com.        IN  A

;; Query time: 119 msec
;; SERVER: 77.68.108.121#53(77.68.108.121)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 30 11:06:18 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 36
```

Comment: heh thanks for the reply. I'll be honest i don't fully understand what the trace etc problem is, but if i configure a ns1.hutber.com zone for wingspartytime.com it should work?

Comment: It's a 2 part configuration that needs to be in place.  First you have to delegate your domain to a name server.  This is done and working as dns queries for wingspartytime.com are making it to your delegated name servers.  The other part is that the dns server that you've delegated to has to have the wingspartytime.com zone file with records to serve.  This appears to be where your problem is as ns*.hutber.com doesn't know how to answer queries to wingspartytime.com zone.  So what company is running ns*.hutber.com?  And where are each of these plesk control panels running?

Comment: Looks like ns*.hutber.com belong to streamline.net based on their reverse dns.  You'll need to add the records you need for wingspartytime.com to their name servers.

Comment: Ok, this kind of makes sense then. The server is hosted by streamline.net and the domain is managed by c2domains.com. In short then, i'll need to transfer the domain to streamline and then set it up to be a ns as i have done with c2domains. I hope that is correct and i've made sense?

Comment: Well right now there are 3 companies involved unless c1domains.com and streamline.net are the same company.  wingspartytime.com is registered at 123-reg, hutber.com is registered at c1domains.com, and the hosting provider is streamline.net.  So is the plesk control panel for hutber.com at streamline.net or c1domains.com?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6894/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-3dinfluence)